# How to skip an operation in 2 layers of loop in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recursion

I am currently working on an ML project and the code structure looks like this. Basically, I want to train 3 different models for 3 different data. Now I know some models fail for some of the products which are fine, I just want to know how I can skip them and move to the next model/product. It is even better if I can completely avoid the looping. Thanks for your time.

```
model = ['a', 'b', 'c']
products = ['x', 'y' 'z']

for i in products:
  for j in model:
     if j == 'a':
       #. training sequence  -------> if this fails move to next elif
       #. save results
     elif j == 'b'
       #. training sequence  -------> if this fails move to next elif
       #. save results
     elif j == 'c'
       #. training sequence
       #. save results
```

Comment: By fail you mean it throws an exception?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes, I am aware of what the exceptions are which are library sepecific, I try to add try-except but it seems too non optimal.

Comment: there is a python keyword that you can use `continue` it will skip the iteration

Comment: Which indicates failure?

Comment: Zero divison error for example.

Comment: `try/except` + `continue` in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Example for the ZeroDivisionError:

```
for i in (2,4):
    for j in ('a','b'):
        try:
            if j=='a':
                print(f'a: i={i} result:{1/(2-i)}')
            if j=='b':
                print(f'b: i={i} result:{1/(4-i)}')
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            continue
```

'b' model acts on 2 and 'a' on 4. Output:

```
b: i=2 result:0.5
a: i=4 result:-0.5
```